# A colleague raised an unfair allegation against me, what should I do?

Tags: people-management

I'm a early childhood educator. We have a sunsmart policy which means all children needs a sunhat to play outside. One day, I saw a child go outside without a sun hat, so I held their hand and led him back inside to find his sun hat. The colleague (A) I worked with later reported to the coordinator, and said that I pushed him and there was a red mark on his arm.

I know this is not true, and I will have to explain this to HR and my manager next Monday. Because there was another educator (B) with (A) at the time, B probably will take A's side, which will mean that it's one against two.

My questions are:

1) Is it possible that I can prove that I didn't do the wrong thing? How should I do? Or how should I defend myself?

2) What should I do, in the worst scenario that I receive an unfair dismissal?

3) Because management will be changing next year, all staff will be made redundant at the end of this year.  Can I still get the redundancy package if I am dismissed?

Comment: Why did colleague A report you?  Are they intentionally lying, or genuinely concerned?

Comment: You seems to be assuming everything is going to go against you.  Can they not just interview the child?

Comment: sounds like a terrible situation, is there any background that would make your word less believable than your colleagues?

Comment: @Frisbee "Early childcare" is Australian for preschool, meaning the kids are likely under 5.  If you "interview" a kid at this age, they will gleefully confess that they flew to the moon or were eaten by lions yesterday.  (Source: I have two kids under 5.)

Comment: Consult a labor lawyer. In this case it is entirely possible they are trying to reduce staff before the official redundancy so they don't have to pay out benefits. This is very definitely a situation where you need a lawyer.

Comment: This is not a question we can help with.  My advice is look in your employee manual and see if there is a process defined for handling this.  Otherwise talk with your management about what is going to happen.  Sorry we can not be of much help to you.

Comment: I think because they always chitchat in the room instead of looking after the children, and I normal don't like talk too much with them.

Comment: What I worried the most is, if I can't prove myself, then will here be a record in the department, and make me can pass work with children check? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) Is it possible that I can prove that I didn't do the wrong thing? How should I do? Or how should I defend myself?

The only way you can prove it in the absence of a corroborating story from a witness is by surveillance tapes or any other recording device that may have captured the event.

> 2) What should I do, in the worst scenario that I receive an unfair dismissal?

If there are multiple witnesses stating that they saw something, then you are going to find it very difficult to prove that the dismissal is unfair.

> 3) Because management will be changing next year, all staff will be made redundant at the end of this year. Can I still get the redundancy package if I am dismissed?

This is something you will have to take up with a lawyer or a union rep if you have one.  Honestly, you are best off talking to a lawyer anyway.  It sounds like you may be in for a bit of a battle, and you will need to speak with someone who can give you salient advice with all of the information.

Comment: Should this be migrated this to Law?